# Would it make any difference giving arguments using scanner class instead of command line arguments?

Tags: java

package Part1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

**String a = args[1]**; // While executing, **arguments given as - java Class1 1 2 3 4**

System.out.println(a);

**Scanner** Scan = new **Scanner**(System.in);// **User input is: 1**

int inputnumber= Scan.nextInt();

System.out.println(inputnumber);

**// Is Scanner class an alternative to command line arguments?**

```
}
```

}

Comment: Please do not be in a hurry to ask question. Just by providing a code that only provides a `System.out` does not help. Please read documentations for this

Comment: Think of a system where you need to start your JVM (that say takes a greeting string to greet user) automatically on a daily basis, are you expecting people to type in by using scanner api or you pass those as a string?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of your question (i.e., comparing to main method's arguments), the `Scanner` class works better for interactive sessions where the user is available for supplying the input interactively. But it also works with streams, files, and readers, etc.

This is more suitable when a user interacts with the program by starting it manually.

The `main` method's arguments, however, can be sent to the program even when the program is started programmatically or by schedulers, etc. 

Although software can be programmed to send interactive input to other programs, the main program's arguments work better in non-interactive sessions.

Comment: Please elaborate!

Comment: @Prashant if I call my Java program like that `java -jar my jar delete filename` then I could run it from cron or whatever scheduler is available without supplying any values at runtime.
But if my program reads action (delete) and filename during runtime then for every run I need a person who will actually type it in console after program is started.

Answer (score 2):

Command line arguments are configuration parameters of the process. They may change the processing flow and how data is processed.

Scanner reads data from the input stream. This is an actual data to be processed, not configuration.